# GA4 Api - How to filter metrics with php library

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am trying to filter dimensions with the GA4 api php library. Unfortunately, it is still in beta and I can't find any php examples on how to filter dimensions.

My code returns "Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\NumericValue."

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' => 'yesterday',
                    'end_date' => 'yesterday',
                ]),
            ],
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension([
                    'name' => 'eventName',
                ]),
            ],
            'metrics' => [new Metric(
                [
                    'name' => 'eventCount',
                ])
            ],
            
            'metricFilter' => new FilterExpression([
                'filter' => new Filter([
                    'field_name' => 'eventCount',
                    'numeric_filter' => new Filter\NumericFilter([
                        'operation' => Filter\NumericFilter\Operation::GREATER_THAN,
                        'value' => '10000',
                    ])
                ]),
            ]),
            
        ]);
```

Here is the JSON version of the request from the api explorer:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "eventName"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "eventCount"
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "yesterday",
      "endDate": "yesterday"
    }
  ],
  "metricFilter": {
    "filter": {
      "fieldName": "eventCount",
      "numericFilter": {
        "operation": "GREATER_THAN",
        "value": {
          "int64Value": "10000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656948/how-to-use-multiple-filters-with-google-analytics-data-api-ga4-using-php/72657630#72657630) on similar question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I decided to leave this post since there is very little out there about filtering the ga4 api.

````
'metricFilter' => new FilterExpression([
                'filter' => new Filter([
                    'field_name' => 'eventCount',
                    'numeric_filter' => new Filter\NumericFilter([
                        'operation' => Filter\NumericFilter\Operation::GREATER_THAN,
                        'value' => new NumericValue([
                            'int64_value'  =>  '10000'
                        ]),
                    ])
                ]),
            ]),
    ```
````